# YUI - remove select options

Tags: javascript, yui

I have an HTML select element with some countries as the options.

```
<select id="countryLocation" class="selectCountryPrefix enablePartialForm" onchange="document.locationchangeform.submit()" name="country">
    <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" value="">Select country</option>
    <option class="showTos-AU" title="+61" value="AU">Australia</option>
    <option class="showTos-CA" title="+1" value="CA">Canada</option>
    <option class="showTos-CL" title="+56" value="CL">Chile</option>
    <option class="showTos-DK" title="+45" value="DK">Denmark</option>
    <option class="showTos-EE" title="+372" value="EE">Estonia</option>
    <option class="showTos-FI" title="+358" value="FI">Finland</option>
    <option class="showTos-GR" title="+30" value="GR">Greece</option>
    <option class="showTos-HU" title="+36" value="HU">Hungary</option>
    <option class="showTos-IE" title="+353" value="IE">Ireland</option>
    <option class="default showTos-LV" selected="selected" title="+371" value="LV">Latvia</option>
    <option class="showTos-TW" title="+886" value="TW">Taiwan</option>
</select>
```

I want to remove all of the options that have a country code not equal to "TW". So far this is my code:

```
YAHOO.util.Event.addListener(window, "load", function() {

    var E = YAHOO.util.Event;
    var D = YAHOO.util.Dom;

    var opts,
        select,
        i;

    select = D.get('countryLocation');
    opts = select.options;
    for (i=0; i< opts.length-1; i++){
        if (opts[i].value !== ""){
            if (opts[i].value !== "TW"){
                select.remove(i);
            }
        } 
    }

})
```

it only works on some of the options - I'm guessing that because it's removing them by index then the indexes are changing after each one is removed. What I really want it something like the jQuery .each() function.

How can I do this either in YUI or just plain JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach (in regard to Brant Olsen's answer) is to iterate backwards:

```
for (i=opts.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
    if (opts[i].value !== ""){
        if (opts[i].value !== "TW"){
            select.remove(i);
        }
    } 
}
```

I usually go with this approach when deleting objects from an array (within an iteration).

Answer (score 1):

After you remove an option, you want to decrement your `i` value. Otherwise, you will be skipping every option that comes after the one you remove.

```
for (i=0; i< opts.length-1; i++){
    if (opts[i].value !== ""){
        if (opts[i].value !== "TW"){
            select.remove(i);
            --i;
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: It appears that this method would only work if all of the options had a country code. In actual fact the first option 'Select country' doesn't and so I end up with an extra country remaining